# Notification if battery drains faster than N% per hour?

Tags: battery

Is there any app or other tool to trigger a notification if the phone's battery drains faster than a certain amount per hour?

Note that I am **not** looking for notifications about apps using too much CPU. I don't want a CPU measurement, I really want a battery measurement: I'm specifically only looking for a way to get a notification when the drain is too fast over some period of time (e.g. say 10% over 1 hour), especially when the phone is idle, regardless of what the phone is doing or not doing.

Comment: You can use [tag:automation] to easily do this

Comment: @beeshyams: I actually started doing this via Tasker, but it seems to me that doing it robustly is not so easy.

Comment: Ok. I am not familiar with Tasker. Please [edit] to add what you tried in Tasker and tasker experts can help you. Also add the relevant tags to your question

Comment: @beeshyams: I haven't "tried" yet, I merely started writing the code... not sure what tags you'd like me to add either.

Comment: If you are gong to ask for Tasker help, then Tasker and automation. If not, it's fine. BTW, you can try MacroDroid app. You have a template section within the app. You will find some useful templates that are close to what you want to do and may need just a little tweaking (search in top rated templates)

Comment: There is no straightforward way to measure power usage for single app, you need samples and then some simple AI for power usage calculation based on hw usage (cpu, ram, wifi, gyro, led, gpu, ...) and then you can estimate power requirements for app.

Comment: @SampoSarrala: Where did I ask for measuring power usage for a single app?

Comment: @mehrdad well, theres hudreds apps that does exactly what you're asking and therefore I thought maybe you want something more. You also noted that you might be building custom solution and thought that this might be helpful reminder, maybe it was not that useful for you. You can flag my comment as not needed if you think it wont be useful for anyone.